# Make desktop background true black (OLED)

Tags: 20.04, desktop-background

I am trying to set a totally black background on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I have tried to set a black wallpaper image and have also tried to remove the image and set it via hex code.

My OLED screen is still lighting up in a dark gray tint. It's not completely black as it should be.

On my Windows machine when I use a solid black background the pixels on my OLED don't light up at all.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check your kernel version: `uname -r` If it's not version 5.12 or greater, you may want to upgrade. The kernel didn't support OLED until then.

Comment: `5.15.0-52-generic` so this one should work?

Comment: There should be kernel support there, so the problem is probably something else.

Comment: Could it bee that my other computers are able to send HDR signals, but this old dell with Ubuntu aint able to do that?

Comment: That would be a question for Dell support, I'm afraid. But depending on what you mean by "old" it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Ok, but could the non HDR signal be a problem you think?
When i put on HDR settings on my other computers it goes from gray tint to totaly black.

Comment: I really don't know. I'm not a hardware guy. I'm barely a software guy. But it seems sensible to me that it's either hardware or a driver.

Comment: @EricAndresen You don't mention your actual computer or GPU model in the question, but I would recommend just looking up whether those models actually do support OLED.  As you've said, it's an "old Dell", so it might predate hardware OLED support.  The only other possibility I can think of would be the HDMI cable, but I would recommend confirming hardware support first.

Comment: Thank you, will look in to that and i also think that it might be a hardware problem rather then software. 
The cable i am using is a USB C -> HDMI that i bought specific for this and works with 4k 120Hz HDR on another device i have.